# Is there a way to list all properties that object takes in WebStorm typescript?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I want to see all the properties that object takes. [image]

In VS I can do it
[image]
But in WebStorm it shows hints only when you start typing
[image]
Is there a way to show all possible properties that object takes without typing any letters?

I've tried changing "Inlay hints" settings in preferences, but It look like there is no such a setting.
Maybe there is a hotkey for this but I could not find it

Answer (score 5):

Win: ctrl + space

Mac: ^ + space, but it might not work because mac has the same bind for language swapping

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use **MacOs keybinding** in WebStorm: Have to turn off the key binding for Language Switcher in MacOs Setting.
2. If you use **VSCode keybinding** in WebStorm: you can use **`Cmd + I`** without turn off built-in key binding in OS setting.